# Ruby on Rails custom search feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an attribute Score in my "sheet" model which updates Daily, I want to give user feature that user can search sheets where an average of sheets for the last 5 days is greater than 50 or any other number how can I implement this feature?

eg.- score average for last 10 days > 40,

```
 score average for  last 30 days > 60
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new model eg. Score, and save each value daily as a new entry (instead of overwriting them). Then either calculate your average on the fly in your DB query, or add eg. average_score_5_days, average_score_10_days, etc. fields to your Sheet model and update them daily.